# How to call an object's methods in touchesBegan when touched?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

So in `MyScene.m` I create my Balloon objects and put it in the scene.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    Balloon *balloonObject = [[Balloon alloc] init];
    balloonObject.position = CGPointMake(50 + (75 * i), self.size.height*.5);
    [_balloonsArray addObject:balloonObject];
}

while (_balloonsArray.count > 0) {
    [self addChild:[_balloonsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    [_balloonsArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

That gives me 4 balloons on my screen. In the `Balloon.h` file I have a method called `-(void)shrink` which I want to get called on the tapped balloonObject inside the `-(void)touchesBegan` method. I have tried this code below but it gives me a `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKSpriteNode shrink]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17010c210'` error.

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        Balloon *node = (Balloon *)[self  nodeAtPoint:location];

        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"balloon"]) {

            [node shrink];
        }
}
```

Balloon.h

```
@interface Balloon : SKSpriteNode

-(void)shrink;

@end
```

Balloon.m

```
@implementation Balloon
{
    SKSpriteNode *_balloon;
}

-(id)init{

    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        _balloon = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"balloonPicture"];
        _balloon.name = @"balloon";
        _balloon.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

        [self addChild:_balloon];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)shrink{

    // does something
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `Balloon.h` and `Balloon.m` files?

Comment: As well as where you set the name of your balloons to `@"balloon"`

Comment: Another way of approaching your goal would be to uniquely name your balloon objects, add them to an array (like you do), enumerate the array to find the balloon being touched by name and then running the shrink method.

Comment: @BenKane I've added the .h and .m files.

Comment: @sangony I'm having problems with running the method once I find the object being touched, it gives me this:                 ``NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKSpriteNode shrink]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17010c210'`` error.

Comment: You do realize in your init method you are adding balloon to balloon?

Comment: @sangony I'm not really sure what I'm doing.. but I can see how that might be a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your balloon init. Instead of using the Balloon class you are creating child SKSpriteNode and setting the name to balloon. This is why you are getting a SKSpriteNode and not a Balloon.

You could do something like this instead.

```
-(id)init{

    self = [super init];
    if (self){

        self.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"balloonPicture"];
        self.size = self.texture.size;
        self.name = @"balloon";
        self.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    }

    return self;
}
```

In your Scene where you create the balloon

```
Ballon *balloon = [[Balloon alloc]init];
[self addChild:balloon];
```